# What is the name of this dialog box that some apps create, which gets stuck above the taskbar over other applications?

Tags: windows-11, gui, modern-ui

The below is an example of the dialog box I am talking about. The example is created when I use the word app, but a similar dialog appears from software I have paired with my logitech craft keyboard. It is not a dialog box I see used often but it very frequently gets stuck and doesn't go away. I would like to know at least the name of it so I can learn if there are keyboard shortcuts to remove it or if I have to force it to go away somehow.
[Example dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIzRg.png)

Comment: It's a windowless application, but knowing that alone doesn't help with removing/closing it. More relevant is the name of the executable, as found in Task Manager.

Comment: It would be a Windows notification, if you see it on the bottom-right of the screen. You can set the parameters on *Settings > System > Notifications & actions*.